# Bootstrap 3 fixed navbar 3 columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want my Bootstrap 3 navbar to be split in 3 regions, as in this example:

[image]

I tried giving the navbar-form (search bar) this CSS:

```
.navbar-form .form-control
  display: inline-block
  width: 100%
  vertical-align: middle

.navbar-form
  overflow: auto

.navbar-form .form-group
  display: inline
```

However, the navbar-right part is then in the next row.

The search box is supposed to be width 100% (fluid).

Thanks

Comment: where is your html?

Comment: Please share some fiddle with HTML & css.